# converting foreach to filter

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to convert

```
List<FlightPositionRoute> flightPositionRoutes = new ArrayList<>();

            dtos.stream()
                    .map(a-> positions.getPositions(a.getId()
                            .getValue()))
                    .forEach(flightPositionRoute -> 
                               flightPositionRoute.ifPresent(flightPositionRoutes::add));
```

To this:

```
List<FlightPositionRoute> flightPositionRoutes = dtos.stream()
                    .map(a-> positions.getPositions(a.getId()
                            .getValue()))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I mean I would like to use filter instead of `foreach`, because it's prettier ;)

Unfortunately, I'm getting

```
Required type: List <FlightPositionRoute>
Provided: List <Optional<FlightPositionRoute>>
```

How can I repair it?

Comment: `....filter(Optional::isPresent).map( e -> e.get())...`

Comment: `flatMap` by `Optional:stream` should be enough: `dtos.stream().map(a-> positions.getPositions(a.getId().getValue())).flatMap(Optional::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());` will provide `List<FlightPositionRoute>`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to unpack the `Optional`:

```
List<FlightPositionRoute> flightPositionRoutes = dtos.stream()
    .map(a-> positions.getPositions(a.getId().getValue()))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```